# ffmpeg compilation Error

Tags: python, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi2

I have been trying to compile ffmpeg on my raspberry-pi, but it gives me a lot of warnings like (codec is deprecated) especially while run sudo make.

```
 pi@raspberrypi:/usr/src/ffmpeg $ sudo make && sudo make install

....... lots of successful execution here ...... 


CC  libavfilter/avf_showfreqs.o
libavfilter/lavfutils.c: In function ‘ff_load_image’:
libavfilter/lavfutils.c:53:5: warning: ‘codec’ is deprecated (declared at    ./libavformat/avformat.h:880) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 codec_ctx = format_ctx->streams[0]->codec;
 ^
libavfilter/lavfutils.c:79:5: warning: ‘avcodec_decode_video2’ is deprecated   (declared at ./libavcodec/avcodec.h:4763) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 ret = avcodec_decode_video2(codec_ctx, frame, &frame_decoded, &pkt);
 ^
CC  libavfilter/lswsutils.o
CC  libavfilter/opencl_allkernels.o
CC  libavfilter/pthread.o
CC  libavfilter/setpts.o
CC  libavfilter/settb.o
CC  libavfilter/split.o
CC  libavfilter/src_movie.o
libavfilter/src_movie.c: In function ‘movie_push_frame’:
libavfilter/src_movie.c:524:9: warning: ‘avcodec_decode_video2’ is deprecated (declared at ./libavcodec/avcodec.h:4763) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     ret = avcodec_decode_video2(st->codec_ctx, frame, &got_frame, pkt);
     ^
libavfilter/src_movie.c:527:9: warning: ‘avcodec_decode_audio4’ is deprecated (declared at ./libavcodec/avcodec.h:4714) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     ret = avcodec_decode_audio4(st->codec_ctx, frame, &got_frame, pkt);
     ^
CC  libavfilter/transform.o
CC  libavfilter/trim.o
CC  libavfilter/vaf_spectrumsynth.o
libavfilter/vaf_spectrumsynth.c: In function ‘try_push_frame’:
libavfilter/vaf_spectrumsynth.c:370:19: warning: variable ‘ret’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
 int ch, n, i, ret;                 ^
CC  libavfilter/vf_alphamerge.o
CC  libavfilter/vf_aspect.o
CC  libavfilter/vf_atadenoise.o
CC  libavfilter/vf_colorlevels.o
CC  libavfilter/vf_colorspace.o
libavfilter/vf_colorspace.c: In function ‘fill_rgb2xyz_table’:
libavfilter/vf_colorspace.c:360:22: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘invert_matrix3x3’ from incompatible pointer type
 invert_matrix3x3(rgb2xyz, i);
                  ^
libavfilter/vf_colorspace.c:277:13: note: expected ‘const double (*)[3]’ but argument is of type ‘double (*)[3]’
 static void invert_matrix3x3(const double in[3][3], double out[3][3])
         ^
libavfilter/vf_colorspace.c: In function ‘fill_whitepoint_conv_table’:
libavfilter/vf_colorspace.c:424:21: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘mul3x3’   from incompatible pointer type
 mul3x3(tmp, ma, fac);
libavfilter/vf_colorspace.c:376:13: note: expected ‘const double (*)[3]’ but argument is of type ‘double (*)[3]’
static void mul3x3(double dst[3][3], const double src1[3][3], const double src2[3][3])
         ^
libavfilter/vf_colorspace.c:425:17: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘mul3x3’ from incompatible pointer type
 mul3x3(out, tmp, mai);
             ^
libavfilter/vf_colorspace.c:376:13: note: expected ‘const double (*)[3]’ but argument is of type ‘double (*)[3]’
static void mul3x3(double dst[3][3], const double src1[3][3], const double src2[3][3])
         ^
libavfilter/vf_colorspace.c:425:22: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘mul3x3’ from incompatible pointer type
 mul3x3(out, tmp, mai);
                  ^
libavfilter/vf_colorspace.c:376:13: note: expected ‘const double (*)[3]’ but argument is of type ‘double (*)[3]’
static void mul3x3(double dst[3][3], const double src1[3][3], const double src2[3][3])
         ^
libavfilter/vf_colorspace.c: In function ‘convert’:
libavfilter/vf_colorspace.c:480:20: warning: passing argument 7 of ‘s->yuv2yuv’ from incompatible pointer type
                s->yuv2yuv_coeffs, s->yuv_offset);
                ^
libavfilter/vf_colorspace.c:480:20: note: expected ‘const int16_t (*)[3][8]’ but argument is of type ‘int16_t (*)[3][8]’
libavfilter/vf_colorspace.c:480:39: warning: passing argument 8 of ‘s->yuv2yuv’ from incompatible pointer type
                s->yuv2yuv_coeffs, s->yuv_offset);
                                   ^
libavfilter/vf_colorspace.c:480:39: note: expected ‘const int16_t (*)[8]’ but argument is of type ‘int16_t (*)[8]’
libavfilter/vf_colorspace.c:502:20: warning: passing argument 7 of ‘s->yuv2rgb’ from incompatible pointer type
                s->yuv2rgb_coeffs, s->yuv_offset[0]);
                ^
libavfilter/vf_colorspace.c:502:20: note: expected ‘const int16_t (*)[3][8]’ but argument is of type ‘int16_t (*)[3][8]’
libavfilter/vf_colorspace.c:506:62: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘s->dsp.multiply3x3’ from incompatible pointer type
             s->dsp.multiply3x3(rgb, s->rgb_stride, w, h, s->lrgb2lrgb_coeffs);
                                                          ^
libavfilter/vf_colorspace.c:506:62: note: expected ‘const int16_t (*)[3][8]’ but argument is of type ‘int16_t (*)[3][8]’
libavfilter/vf_colorspace.c:511:28: warning: passing argument 7 of ‘s->rgb2yuv_fsb’ from incompatible pointer type
                        s->rgb2yuv_coeffs, s->yuv_offset[1], s->dither_scratch);
                        ^
libavfilter/vf_colorspace.c:511:28: note: expected ‘const int16_t (*)[3][8]’ but argument is of type ‘int16_t (*)[3][8]’
libavfilter/vf_colorspace.c:514:24: warning: passing argument 7 of ‘s->rgb2yuv’ from incompatible pointer type
                    s->rgb2yuv_coeffs, s->yuv_offset[1]);
                    ^
libavfilter/vf_colorspace.c:514:24: note: expected ‘const int16_t (*)[3][8]’ but argument is of type ‘int16_t (*)[3][8]’
libavfilter/vf_colorspace.c: In function ‘create_filtergraph’:
libavfilter/vf_colorspace.c:614:30: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘invert_matrix3x3’ from incompatible pointer type

                 ^
```

and it still continues....

How to solve it? what might be the problem for this warnings?

Comment: Can you provide the version you are using?

Comment: I am using ffmpeg 3.1.1

Comment: try this one: http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/release-source/ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **don't compile as root**.

You should run `make` as your normal user, without `sudo`.

Only run `sudo make install` if you're installing in a root-owned location (e.g `/usr` or `/usr/local`).

---

As for your question, the warnings seem to come from the ffmpeg code, not something you've done by compiling it.

It could be that you're using a newer gcc than the ffmpeg developers, and your newer version reports warnings for stuff that used to be considered ok. Or it could be that you used some gcc options that turn on some warnings, and the ffmpeg developers have those turned off. Or it could be that the ffmpeg also saw those warnings when compiling, and decided to ignore them.

But those are just warnings, that is the compiler is telling you « this is fishy, you might want to check it, but it's probably going to be ok ». So unless you're identifying actual problems, you can either ignore them, or send a patch upstream that changes the code in a way that the warning disappears (and that the code remains correct, of course).

For example, I see an instance of `warning: variable ‘ret’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]`. Well, you could send upstream a patch that removes the definition of that variable, and just like that, one warning would be gone. :)

There is no error in the output you provided though, so I assume your compilation succeeded, and you're happily using your fresh build of ffmpeg now.

Or is there an actual error you didn't paste here?

Comment: yeah, compilation is succeeded and there is no error but all seems to be a warning only. may i need to worry about those warnings?

Comment: Unless you can read and fix the source code, there's no need to worry about them, no. :)

Comment: I was worried about this a lot. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Yes you really need to worry about warnings as well. May be not now when you will be using ffmpeg in production, for example:::::::::: libavfilter/lavfutils.c:53:5: warning: ‘codec’ is deprecated (declared at    ./libavformat/avformat.h:880) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 codec_ctx = format_ctx->streams[0]->codec;:::::::::: completely shows that you can't use codec function, make sure use the documentation from source, simple copy-paste instruction from web might not work, which could be based on old version that is already depreciated.

Comment: @arshpreet: I agree with you that when coding to an API, you need to worry about the warnings. But that's not what sivamnatesan3 is doing here, they are just compiling ffmpeg itself, and the warnings are in the ffmpeg code.